# How to use 3G module

Tags: windows, 3g

Hi all I have something like this:

[image: THIS]

which is a 3G module.

Problem is, when I was ordering I though I will get a 3G module with SIM card slot.

Now I can't put SIM card in it. Any idea what I can do? Is there any SIM card slot or something similar?

I need cheap solution something around 10$ because this costed me 30$. And going above that price is not cheap solution. Any idea is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a laptop. If so, you'll want to consult your manual as to whether or not the laptop comes with a SIM slot. If it does, it's usually underneath the battery, so you could start by looking there. If your laptop doesn't have a SIM slot, then I don't think you can use the 3G card because the card doesn't have its own SIM slot.

Comment: Yes, I think this answer is correct.  My ThinkPad X200s has a separate SIM slot, and it is my understanding that not all X200/X200s models are "WWAN Ready".

Comment: But shouldn't I be able to by a SIM card reader that supports CDMA and I with my 3G module I can make an internet connection?

Comment: @denonth: Oh, is it a CMDA card?  I didn't think CMDA uses SIM cards?

Comment: yes it is 3G module cdma can I use external sim card reader?